# Android: mixing localization language

Tags: android, localization

I am having troubles in displaying the correct language in the main.java. On some devices (eg. galaxy nexus) the language is correctly displayed like the /res/values-de. On some devices, eg htc legend or samsung ace, the main.java is in English, and the following pages are in German. The logging in the main.java says the locale is to "DE"...

Has anybody an idea how to solve this?

Any help would be very appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your phone language settings.
You can change language settings in code, but not forget to change to default after closing your app.

```
//in onCreate();
Resources standardResources = getApplicationContext();
DisplayMetrics metrics = standardResources.getDisplayMetrics();
Configuration config = new Configuration(standardResources.getConfiguration());
config.locale = new Locale("de") // change
standardResources.updateConfiguration(config, metrics);

// in onDestroy()
config.locale = Locale.getDefault(); // default
standardResources.updateConfiguration(config, metrics);
```

Comment: this i tried already, but with no effect, still the same prob. i am in the end of any ideas :(

Answer (score 0):

Check to see if all your country codes are correct

- http://colincooper.net/blog/2011/02/17/android-supported-language-and-locales/

Comment: the countrycodes are correct, the thing is, that on some phones it is ok and on some not. and on all devices the second loaded page is in german

Comment: Are all the devices that you are testing on 2.3+? Because as that link says some language codes were not available until 2.3

Comment: Are you sure that all the `values` XML files contain the same strings, is it possible that there are some missing from certain languages?

Comment: If you remove all but one of the languages what happens?